# Breaking out of a for loop upon invalid user entry

Tags: c#, loops

**edit: for those who have answered, I apologize, I should have been more clear, the assignment REQUIRES use of the for loop per my professor.**

I'm doing a small assignment for class and am having trouble breaking out of a for loop and prompting the user to enter a valid value. My code is set up thus far as:

```
const int MINRANGE = 1;
const int MAXRANGE = 20;
int input = 0;

Console.Write("Enter the desired maximum: ");

string strInput = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n");


for (int.TryParse(strInput, out input); input >= MINRANGE && input <= MAXRANGE; input--)
{

        Console.WriteLine("{0,2}   {1,5}", input, Math.Pow(input, 3));

}
```

The program displays everything I need it to correctly. When the user enters a value out of the range I have specified, I need to give them a short message and then break out of the loop and return to the beginning prompt. I think I need to use something like the following if statement:

```
if (input >= MAXRANGE || input <= MINRANGE)
{
    Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid value, please try again.");
}
```

Perhaps with a break; following it? But I'm not sure how to use it inside of the for loop. I've tried placing it outside, but that doesn't get me back to the user prompt, but neither does placing it inside the loop, so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: Where though? Does it matter? I've placed it at the end and it gives me the proper message "That is not a valid...." but it doesn't bring me back to the prompt. I tried adding break; at the end, same problem.

Comment: If you are requiring the user to re-enter values and you want to send them back to the beginning of the process, you can use a while loop over the question and until they get it write then move onto the next part.

Comment: You might want to put the whole block inside a while loop, that way, when you break out of the inner loop, you will restart the whole block.

Comment: I thought about using a while loop, but the professor specifically said to do this section in a for loop. I guess they didn't say anything about not putting the for loop inside a while loop. I'll give that a shot now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a while loop

```
int input;
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input) || input >= MAXRANGE)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not valid!");
}
```

Note that this may get the user "stuck" and a helpful message as to why it isn't valid would be nice

---

If for some bizarre reason you *must* use a for loop you can use the following but it is horrible code that I would never condone

```
int input;
for(;;)
{
    if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input) && input < MAXRANGE)
        break;
}
```

Comment: `for(;;)` can be a `while (true)`. Still you shouldn't use it but it is more straightforward to read.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Yeah, the op left a comment above stating "but the professor specifically said to do this section in a for loop", I don't agree with this professor :)

Comment: I agree with your disagreement. ;)

Comment: I think it's meant to challenge us, this is just an intro to OOP class. This is an extra credit assignment with multiple parts. I used other loop structures elsewhere, but this one requires a for loop.

Comment: @bnr32jason - I thought that might be the case and it is worth stressing that for loops tend to be used when you have a fixed length of iterations.. whilst it can be used for infinite iterations as shown in my answer; you will just be opening yourself up for some other developer to misinterpretting your intentions and thusly breaking your code :)

Comment: The loop will run anywhere between 1 and 20 times based on the user input, so yeah I guess it's not really fixed. Is there any way we could chat a little, I think I know what you are saying, but I'm some trouble deciphering how to apply your recommended code. Thanks!

Comment: @bnr32jason - Sure ask away, eventually comment enough and an option to continue in chat should appear :) (May take me a while to respond though!)

Comment: I figured it out thanks! I ended up using a while loop with a boolean statement and then put the for loop inside the while loop. Took me some trial and error but figured it out and learned something in the process. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its better to do the validation before entering the loop. Try this out.....

```
const int MINRANGE = 1;
const int MAXRANGE = 20;
int input = 0;

Console.Write("Enter the desired maximum: ");

string strInput = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n");
if (input > MAXRANGE || input < MINRANGE)
{
    Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid value, please try again.");
}
else
{
        for (int.TryParse(strInput, out input); input >= MINRANGE && input <= 
        MAXRANGE; input--)
         {

           Console.WriteLine("{0,2}   {1,3}", input, Math.Pow(input, 3));

         }
}
```

Comment: This won't work since input will always be less than the `MINRANGE`

Comment: Ah, yes, that's true. I tried this code and was wondering why it wasn't processing my data input even with a valid number.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ([(fist) Initialization];
     [(second)Condition];
     [(third or exit the loop) Progression])
     {
            [(fourth) Loop's body -if we reached third than we got here ]        
     }
```

The for loop is constructed of three parts:

1. The initialization part which happens only once when the loop starts.
2. The condition evaluation part which happens for every iteration.
3. The indexer progression part which also happens for every loop.
   The order is as follows: 
   Start Loop => init => CheckCondition => if OK Progress the indexer and execute loop's body, else the loop is done.

The initialization part happens just once, if you want it to happen foreach interation it should be inside the loop or in the conditional section of the loop instead.

Best practice would be to use a while loop when the number of iterations is unknown ahead, like in this case, when it's determined by user's input.

Comment: I'm following you, but the user input variable "input" is a part of my initialization and conditions of the loop. If I place the prompt inside the loop, what do I use for my initialization and conditions of the loop?

Comment: You leave the initialization and the progression parts empty and use only the conditional part .
for(;[code only here];)
{
}

Comment: Thank you. I did it slightly differently bit you helped me get on the right track. I left the initialization blank and filled in the other two.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your code as follows. Creating a method for asking the input:

```
const int MINRANGE = 1;
const int MAXRANGE = 20;
int input = 0;

string strInput = AskInput();

while (!int.TryParse(strInput, out input)) /*while the number is invalid*/
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your input is invalid. Try again.");
    strInput = AskInput();
}

while (input >= MINRANGE && input <= MAXRANGE)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,2}   {1,3}", input, Math.Pow(input, 3));

    input--;
}
```

Where `AskInput` is:

```
private static string AskInput()
{
    Console.Write("Enter the desired maximum: ");

    string strInput = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n");

    return strInput;
}
```